# Why does workbook turns hidden after vba executes

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Here is the sub

```
Sub test()
With ThisWorkbook
.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 5
.Save
End With
End Sub
```

Here is the vbscript that starts the sub

```
dim eApp
set eApp = GetObject("C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Book1.xlsm")
eApp.Application.Run "Book1.xlsm!test"
set eApp = nothing
```

It executes fine but the workbook gets hidden for some reason . I have to unhide it `View - -> Unhide`

Why does this happen and how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A clearer way of running your `vbs` would be as follows

```
Dim ObjExcel, ObjWB
Set ObjExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set ObjWB = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Book1.xlsm")
'make it visible
ObjExcel.Visible = True
ObjExcel.Run "Book1.xlsm!test"
ObjWB.Close False
ObjExcel.Quit
Set ObjExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you . But I got a run time error : `Object doesn't support this property or methods : Visible` https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41007907/Untitled.png

Comment: Poor editing on my behalf between VBA and VBS - should have referred to the Application (`ObjExcel`). Now fixed.

Comment: You can't call `ObjExcel.Quit` after releasing the object reference the line before (`Set ObjExcel = Nothing`). That's going to cause an error.

Comment: Hmmm, Maybe I misunderstood OP? `CreateObject` or `GetObject` does not hide the workbooks.

Comment: @SiddharthRout My answer is ambigious, whichh I need to rectify. I meant a new application isnt automatically visible. But using `GetObject` as above does indeed open a workbook in the `VBE` that can't be viewed as part of the Application

Comment: Ah ok... so OP is actually talking about the application and not the workbook? `It executes fine but the workbook gets hidden for some reason .`